# vitetest: Failed to resolve import "$lib/stores/store"

Tags: testing, vite, sveltekit

tried running tests with vitest and it can seem to resolve dependencies from `$lib/*` and `$app/*` this is the error, `Failed to resolve import "$lib/stores/store" from "src/lib/components/Hello.svelte". Does the file exist?` here is the link to the playground https://gitlab.com/paulwvnjohi/hello-vitest
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems Vitest is NOT automatically picking up your Vite config, since it's "hidden" in `svelte.config.js` and I'm sure there's tons of magic stuff SvelteKit adds, such as the `resolve.alias` paths for things like the `$lib` and `$app` imports to work.

I don't know if Vitest core would do something automatically in the future, but now there's the `vitest-svelte-kit` package you can use: https://github.com/nickbreaton/vitest-svelte-kit

Install the package:

```sh
npm i -D vitest-svelte-kit
```

Create a file `vitest.config.js` and put inside the method that magically extracts the correct vite config for you, according to your settings in `svelte.config.js`:

```js
// vitest.config.js
import { extractFromSvelteConfig } from "vitest-svelte-kit"

export default extractFromSvelteConfig()
```

Worked for me!

Comment: + vitest-svelte-kit 0.0.7 deprecated